# Getting Architecture of Windows (32/64 bit version)

Tags: windows, architecture, kernel32

i got a little problem:

im tring to get the architecture of the OS, the problem is my programming language doesnt support such functions. Therefore i need to read this information form an windows dll (like kernel32.dll)
i did try to get the infos with the functions `GetNativeSystemInfo/GetVersionEx/GetSystemInfo`.
Unfortunately i were not able to get the architecture :/

Are there some other Functions to read the architecture in any windows dll?
(it dosnt need to be kernel32 it can be any dll but it must exists in win xp+)

As info: im using Gupta (SQLWindows/Team devoloper)

**Edit1:**

```
typedef struct _SYSTEM_INFO {
  union {
    DWORD  dwOemId;
    struct {
      WORD wProcessorArchitecture;
      WORD wReserved;
    } ;
  } ;
  DWORD     dwPageSize;
  LPVOID    lpMinimumApplicationAddress;
  LPVOID    lpMaximumApplicationAddress;
  DWORD_PTR dwActiveProcessorMask;
  DWORD     dwNumberOfProcessors;
  DWORD     dwProcessorType;
  DWORD     dwAllocationGranularity;
  WORD      wProcessorLevel;
  WORD      wProcessorRevision;
} SYSTEM_INFO;
```

thats the info from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724958(VS.85).aspx), i tried to call this Function with with 10 and 12 Parameters
(Gupta dosnt support structs).
On 32Bit i get:
[alt text http://img714.imageshack.us/img714/1954/32bit.gif](http://img714.imageshack.us/img714/1954/32bit.gif)

on 64Bit i get:
[alt text http://img691.imageshack.us/img691/8978/64bit.gif](http://img691.imageshack.us/img691/8978/64bit.gif)

do i get every time a `0` OemID on 32 bit? or better is the OemID everytiem filled on 64bit version of windows?

Thx for help!!

Greets
Auro

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`GetNativeSystemInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724340(VS.85).aspx) is definitely the function to use. If your app is a native 64-bit app, `GetNativeSystemInfo` is the same as [`GetSystemInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724381(VS.85).aspx); otherwise, if it runs under WOW64, it will return the true system properties, even if it is run in an emulated 32-bit environment.

`GetNativeSystemInfo` fills a [`SYSTEM_INFO`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724958(VS.85).aspx) structure, the `wProcessorArchitecture` member of which tells you whether the system is 32-bit (probably `PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_INTEL`) or 64-bit (probably `PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64`).

If your language does not have a wrapper for this Win API function, to use it, you can employ `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress` as usual, and you need to define the `SYSTEM_INFO` structure, of course.

## Update

I would define

```
typedef struct _SYSTEM_INFO {
  WORD      wProcessorArchitecture;
  WORD      wReserved;
  DWORD     dwPageSize;
  LPVOID    lpMinimumApplicationAddress;
  LPVOID    lpMaximumApplicationAddress;
  DWORD_PTR dwActiveProcessorMask;
  DWORD     dwNumberOfProcessors;
  DWORD     dwProcessorType;
  DWORD     dwAllocationGranularity;
  WORD      wProcessorLevel;
  WORD      wProcessorRevision;
} SYSTEM_INFO;
```

Then `wProcessorArchitecture = 0` on a (common) 32-bit system, and `wProcessorArchitecture = 9` on a (common) 64-bit system. These are just the constants `PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_INTEL` and `PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64`, respectively. These are the common 32-bit and 64-bit architectures. `PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_IA64 = 6` is slightly more uncommon, as is surely `PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_UNKNOWN = 65535`.

## Update

Yes, I see your problem. In C, `union` means that you choose *one* of the options at a time. That is, the structure is either

```
DWORD     dwOemId;
DWORD     dwPageSize;
LPVOID    lpMinimumApplicationAddress;
LPVOID    lpMaximumApplicationAddress;
DWORD_PTR dwActiveProcessorMask;
DWORD     dwNumberOfProcessors;
DWORD     dwProcessorType;
DWORD     dwAllocationGranularity;
WORD      wProcessorLevel;
WORD      wProcessorRevision;
```

**or**

```
WORD      wProcessorArchitecture;
WORD      wReserved;
DWORD     dwPageSize;
LPVOID    lpMinimumApplicationAddress;
LPVOID    lpMaximumApplicationAddress;
DWORD_PTR dwActiveProcessorMask;
DWORD     dwNumberOfProcessors;
DWORD     dwProcessorType;
DWORD     dwAllocationGranularity;
WORD      wProcessorLevel;
WORD      wProcessorRevision;
```

Because one DWORD consists of as many bytes (4) as two words (2×2), the alternatives are just two ways of adressing (and naming) the data of the entire structure. In our case, we are more interested in the `wProcessorArchitecture` word rather then the augment `dwOemId` of `wProcessorArchitecture` and the utterly uninteresting `wReserved` words.

Comment: looks like i cant use GetNativeSystemInfo coze its not clearly readable. Is there a way to read it out of Registry?
im not sure if HKLM\Sorftware\Microsoft\Windows NT\currentVersion\BuildLabEx is save...

Comment: Ahhh now it works perfect :D
yeah the problem were i did call the Function in Kernel32 the false way ...
thx for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I think you do like this,

```
BOOL SafeGetNativeSystemInfo(LPSYSTEM_INFO lpSystemInfo)
{
    BOOL bRet = FALSE;

    do 
    {
        if (lpSystemInfo == NULL)
        {
            break;
        }

        typedef void(WINAPI *GetNativeSystemInfoProc) (LPSYSTEM_INFO lpSystemInfo);
        GetNativeSystemInfoProc pFun = (GetNativeSystemInfoProc)GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle(TEXT("kernel32")), "GetNativeSystemInfo");
        if (NULL != pFun)
        {
            pFun(lpSystemInfo);
        }
        else
        {
            GetSystemInfo(lpSystemInfo);
        }

        bRet = TRUE;
    } while (FALSE);
    return bRet;
}


BOOL GetOSDisplayString( LPTSTR pszOS)
{
    GRS_USEPRINTF();

    OSVERSIONINFOEX osvi = {sizeof(OSVERSIONINFOEX)};
    SYSTEM_INFO si = {};
    BOOL bOsVersionInfoEx;
    DWORD dwType;

    if( !(bOsVersionInfoEx = GetVersionEx ((OSVERSIONINFO *) &osvi)) )
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    //GetSystemInfo(&si);
    if (SafeGetNativeSystemInfo(&si) == FALSE)
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    if ( VER_PLATFORM_WIN32_NT == osvi.dwPlatformId && osvi.dwMajorVersion > 4 )
    {
        StringCchCopy(pszOS, BUFSIZE, _T("Microsoft "));

        if ( osvi.dwMajorVersion == 6 )
        {
            if( 0 == osvi.dwMinorVersion )
            {
                if( osvi.wProductType == VER_NT_WORKSTATION )
                {
                    StringCchCat(pszOS, BUFSIZE, _T("Windows Vista "));
                }
                else
                {
                    StringCchCat(pszOS, BUFSIZE, _T("Windows Server 2008 " ));
                }

            }
            else if( 1 == osvi.dwMinorVersion )
            {
                if( osvi.wProductType == VER_NT_WORKSTATION )
                {
                    StringCchCat(pszOS, BUFSIZE, _T("Windows 7 "));
                }
                else
                {
                    StringCchCat(pszOS, BUFSIZE, _T("Windows Unknown "));
                }
            }
            else
            {
                StringCchCat(pszOS, BUFSIZE, _T("Windows Unknown "));
            }

            GetProductInfo( 6, 0, 0, 0, &dwType);
            switch( dwType )
            {
            case PRODUCT_ULTIMATE:
                StringCchCat(pszOS, BUFSIZE, _T("Ultimate Edition" ));
                break;
            case PRODUCT_HOME_PREMIUM:
                StringCchCat(pszOS, BUFSIZE, _T("Home Premium Edition" ));
                break;
            case PRODUCT_HOME_BASIC:
                StringCchCat(pszOS, BUFSIZE, _T("Home Basic Edition" ));
                break;
            case PRODUCT_ENTERPRISE:
                StringCchCat(pszOS, BUFSIZE, _T("Enterprise Edition" ));
                break;
            case PRODUCT_BUSINESS:
                StringCchCat(pszOS, BUFSIZE, _T("Business Edition" ));
                break;
            case PRODUCT_STARTER:
                StringCchCat(pszOS, BUFSIZE, _T("Starter Edition" ));
                break;
            case PRODUCT_CLUSTER_SERVER:
                StringCchCat(pszOS, BUFSIZE, _T("Cluster Server Edition" ));
                break;
            case PRODUCT_DATACENTER_SERVER:
                StringCchCat(pszOS, BUFSIZE, _T("Datacenter Edition" ));
                break;
            case PRODUCT_DATACENTER_SERVER_CORE:
                StringCchCat(pszOS, BUFSIZE, _T("Datacenter Edition (core installation)" ));
                break;
            case PRODUCT_ENTERPRISE_SERVER:
                StringCchCat(pszOS, BUFSIZE, _T("Enterprise Edition" ));
                break;
            case PRODUCT_ENTERPRISE_SERVER_CORE:
                StringCchCat(pszOS, BUFSIZE, _T("Enterprise Edition (core installation)" ));
                break;
            case PRODUCT_ENTERPRISE_SERVER_IA64:
                StringCchCat(pszOS, BUFSIZE, _T("Enterprise Edition for Itanium-based Systems" ));
                break;
            case PRODUCT_SMALLBUSINESS_SERVER:
                StringCchCat(pszOS, BUFSIZE, _T("Small Business Server" ));
                break;
            case PRODUCT_SMALLBUSINESS_SERVER_PREMIUM:
                StringCchCat(pszOS, BUFSIZE, _T("Small Business Server Premium Edition" ));
                break;
            case PRODUCT_STANDARD_SERVER:
                StringCchCat(pszOS, BUFSIZE, _T("Standard Edition" ));
                break;
            case PRODUCT_STANDARD_SERVER_CORE:
                StringCchCat(pszOS, BUFSIZE, _T("Standard Edition (core installation)" ));
                break;
            case PRODUCT_WEB_SERVER:
                StringCchCat(pszOS, BUFSIZE, _T("Web Server Edition" ));
                break;
            }

            if ( si.wProcessorArchitecture == PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 )
            {
                StringCchCat(pszOS, BUFSIZE, _T( ", 64-bit" ));
            }
            else if (si.wProcessorArchitecture == PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_IA64)
            {
                StringCchCat(pszOS, BUFSIZE, _T(", 64-bit"));
            }
            else if (si.wProcessorArchitecture == PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_ALPHA64)
            {
                StringCchCat(pszOS, BUFSIZE, _T(", 64-bit"));
            }
            else if (si.wProcessorArchitecture == PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_INTEL )
            {
                StringCchCat(pszOS, BUFSIZE, _T(", 32-bit"));
            }
        }

        if ( osvi.dwMajorVersion == 5 && osvi.dwMinorVersion == 2 )
        {
            if( GetSystemMetrics(SM_SERVERR2) )
            {
                StringCchCat(pszOS, BUFSIZE, _T( "Windows Server 2003 R2, "));
            }
            else if ( osvi.wSuiteMask==VER_SUITE_STORAGE_SERVER )
            {
                StringCchCat(pszOS, BUFSIZE, _T( "Windows Storage Server 2003"));
            }
            else if( osvi.wProductType == VER_NT_WORKSTATION &&
                si.wProcessorArchitecture==PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64)
            {
                StringCchCat(pszOS, BUFSIZE, _T( "Windows XP Professional x64 Edition"));
            }
            else 
            {
                StringCchCat(pszOS, BUFSIZE, _T("Windows Server 2003, "));
            }
            if ( osvi.wProductType != VER_NT_WORKSTATION )
            {
                if ( si.wProcessorArchitecture == PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_IA64 )
                {
                    if( osvi.wSuiteMask & VER_SUITE_DATACENTER )
                    {
                        StringCchCat(pszOS, BUFSIZE, _T( "Datacenter Edition for Itanium-based Systems" ));
                    }
                    else if( osvi.wSuiteMask & VER_SUITE_ENTERPRISE )
                    {
                        StringCchCat(pszOS, BUFSIZE, _T( "Enterprise Edition for Itanium-based Systems" ));
                    }
                }

                else if ( si.wProcessorArchitecture==PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 )
                {
                    if( osvi.wSuiteMask & VER_SUITE_DATACENTER )
                    {
                        StringCchCat(pszOS, BUFSIZE, _T( "Datacenter x64 Edition" ));
                    }
                    else if( osvi.wSuiteMask & VER_SUITE_ENTERPRISE )
                    {                   
                        StringCchCat(pszOS, BUFSIZE, _T( "Enterprise x64 Edition" ));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        StringCchCat(pszOS, BUFSIZE, _T( "Standard x64 Edition" ));
                    }
                }

                else
                {
                    if ( osvi.wSuiteMask & VER_SUITE_COMPUTE_SERVER )
                    {
                        StringCchCat(pszOS, BUFSIZE, _T( "Compute Cluster Edition" ));
                    }
                    else if( osvi.wSuiteMask & VER_SUITE_DATACENTER )
                    {
                        StringCchCat(pszOS, BUFSIZE, _T( "Datacenter Edition" ));
                    }
                    else if( osvi.wSuiteMask & VER_SUITE_ENTERPRISE )
                    {
                        StringCchCat(pszOS, BUFSIZE, _T( "Enterprise Edition" ));
                    }
                    else if ( osvi.wSuiteMask & VER_SUITE_BLADE )
                    {
                        StringCchCat(pszOS, BUFSIZE, _T( "Web Edition" ));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        StringCchCat(pszOS, BUFSIZE, _T( "Standard Edition" ));
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if ( osvi.dwMajorVersion == 5 && osvi.dwMinorVersion == 1 )
        {
            StringCchCat(pszOS, BUFSIZE, _T("Windows XP "));
            if( osvi.wSuiteMask & VER_SUITE_PERSONAL )
            {
                StringCchCat(pszOS, BUFSIZE, _T( "Home Edition" ));
            }
            else
            {
                StringCchCat(pszOS, BUFSIZE, _T( "Professional" ));
            }
        }

        if ( osvi.dwMajorVersion == 5 && osvi.dwMinorVersion == 0 )
        {
            StringCchCat(pszOS, BUFSIZE, _T("Windows 2000 "));

            if ( osvi.wProductType == VER_NT_WORKSTATION )
            {
                StringCchCat(pszOS, BUFSIZE, _T( "Professional" ));
            }
            else 
            {
                if( osvi.wSuiteMask & VER_SUITE_DATACENTER )
                {
                    StringCchCat(pszOS, BUFSIZE, _T( "Datacenter Server" ));
                }
                else if( osvi.wSuiteMask & VER_SUITE_ENTERPRISE )
                {
                    StringCchCat(pszOS, BUFSIZE, _T( "Advanced Server" ));
                }
                else
                {
                    StringCchCat(pszOS, BUFSIZE, _T( "Server" ));
                }
            }
        }

        // Include service pack (if any) and build number.

        if( _tcslen(osvi.szCSDVersion) > 0 )
        {
            StringCchCat(pszOS, BUFSIZE, _T(" ") );
            StringCchCat(pszOS, BUFSIZE, osvi.szCSDVersion);
        }

        TCHAR buf[80];

        StringCchPrintf( buf, 80, _T(" (build %d)"), osvi.dwBuildNumber);
        StringCchCat(pszOS, BUFSIZE, buf);

        return TRUE; 
    }
    else
    {  
        GRS_PRINTF(_T( "This sample does not support this version of Windows.\n") );
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```