# Detect Windows architecture (32 or 64 bit) with C++ - wProcessorArchitecture shows wrong results

Tags: c++, windows

Im using this tiny piece of code to get to know if my Windows is 32 or 64 bit:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static int is64bitOS()
{
    SYSTEM_INFO si;
    GetSystemInfo(&si);

    if((si.wProcessorArchitecture & PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_IA64)||(si.wProcessorArchitecture & PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64)==64)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

int main()
{
    printf("%d\n", is64bitOS());
    return 0;
}
```

I bought and installed 64 bit version of Windows 7 - however, the above code shows 0 meaning my os is 32 bit ... how to deal with it?

**Ok, my other approaches, which basically do not work as well ...** On my 64-bit Windows 7 I only see 32 bit ..

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>

int getArchType1()
{
    SYSTEM_INFO sysInfo;
    GetSystemInfo(&sysInfo);

    switch(sysInfo.wProcessorArchitecture)
    {
    case 6:
        return 64;
    case 9:
        return 64;
    case 0:
        return 32;
    default:
        return -1;
    }
}

static char *getArchType2()
{
    char *archType = malloc(sizeof(char) * (255));
    memset(archType, '\0', 255);

#if defined _WIN64
    strcpy(archType, "64-bit");
#else
    strcpy(archType, "32-bit");
#endif // defined

    return archType;
}

int main()
{
    char *arch = getArchType1();
    printf("%s\n", arch);
    free(arch);
    printf("%d\n", getArchType2());
    char c;
    scanf("%c", &c);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I take it you tried building this as a 64-bit executable? If you use a 32-bit executable, I expect it to return a 32-bit processor, as most apps would not know what to do if you tell them that they are not on a processor that they are compiled for (same applies to code asking what processor in Linux, 32-bit apps will be told they are on a 32-bit processor, not a 64-bit one)

Comment: Im building my code with Code::Blocks (single file) so I guess its by default 32 bits. How and where can I change it?

Comment: Yes, the wow64 emulator that allows 32-bit code to run on a 64-bit operating system does a very convincing job :) Trying to defeat it is a bit pointless, you ought to just target x64. You'll never have a problem on a 32-bit operating system, somebody else got *that* wrong.

Comment: The result of a boolean OR operation is not going to equal 64.

Answer (score 11):

From MSDN:

[GetNativeSystemInfo function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724340%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> Retrieves information about the current system to an application running under WOW64. If the function is called from a 64-bit application, it is equivalent to the `GetSystemInfo` function.

There is a hint right there in [GetSystemInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724381%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) description:

> To retrieve accurate information for an application running on WOW64, call the `GetNativeSystemInfo` function.

It basically explains that you were requesting information about environment you're on, rather than real system architecture.

And it gives you another hint as well, that on 64-bit Windows you can have both code executed: `Win32` and `x64`, it is up to you what platform to target.

See also:

- [Is there a Windows API call that will tell me if I'm running on a 64-bit OS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646418/is-there-a-windows-api-call-that-will-tell-me-if-im-running-on-a-64-bit-os)
- [Getting Architecture of Windows (32/64 bit version)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3179916/getting-architecture-of-windows-32-64-bit-version?rq=1)
- [Right way to detect cpu architecture?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2017409/right-way-to-detect-cpu-architecture)

Comment: I came up with this solution: http://pastie.org/private/u6m3uqtcp6cswf0fkpa09a. Will it be cross-platform (appropriate among all compilers (Im interested mainly in GCC and VS) and Windows versions)?

Comment: No, this does not get you architecture of the OS, because you need to query OS, as mentioned above.

Comment: Huh, did another code: http://pastie.org/pastes/9146253/text?key=iq9rpcoqkz8fy7gtztretw but when compiled (I compile it on 32 bit OS and run the `*.exe` on 64 bit OS) it only shows 32 bit ...